# Detect conflicting forwarded ports on VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am using Oracle VirtualBox on Windows. I've setup NAT and forwarded ports.

When some forwarded ports are accidentally conflicting with host machine's ones, no errors are shown and all forwarded ports are failing.

Is there any possibility to detect those conflicting ports? I have used VBoxManage tool and there are neither output messages, nor verbose mode for `startvm` command.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a combination of `netstat` and `VBoxManage` and parse the output. You can easily replace the `findstr` command with `grep` on non-Windows hosts.

**First**, I would get a listing of NAT ports on the VM in question. The `VBoxManage showvminfo` command will output a bunch of info about the configuration which you can filter to look for just the NAT rules. You will want to look for the *host port* and *protocol* fields in the output (and possibly host ip if configured) as that is what you will be looking to see if it is already in use.

```
C:\>vboxmanage showvminfo Linux  | findstr Rule
NIC 1 Rule(0): protocol=tcp, host ip=, host port=2222, guest ip=, guest port=22
```

**Second**, using the info from above I know I need to check if anything is listening on port TCP port 2222, so I can use the `netstat` command to show me all the listening sockets, filtered by my criteria:

```
C:\>netstat -an | findstr LISTENING | findstr TCP | findstr 2222
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:2222           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Because my guest is already running I can see that it has already grabbed a connection on TCP 2222. If you don't get any output then nothing is listening on that specific port and you are safe to start your VM.